# Need help zozo (ZOZO TOWN) api details

Tags: php, web-services, api, rest, affiliate

I am creating api japan affiliate store using amazon, rakutan, and zozo Using PHP. i got amazon and rakutan api details. but no resource found in zozo(ZOZO TOWN). Any one sucessfully done this api. please guide me.

Where is the WEB SERVICES home page for ZOZO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not resource about ZOZO affiliate because ZOZO affiliate has been closed last year.

http://kirei.biglobe.ne.jp/news/detail/20121111105027_fsn2012-11-11-zozotown-affiliate-close-

Comment: i am refer this link. its true are false. http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1034435085

Comment: ZOZO in Valuecommerece? i am searching Valuecommerece but no resource found about ZOZO